# Can a SSIS package created with VS.net 2008 access a SQL Server 2005 database?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

Can a SSIS package created with VS.net 2008 access a SQL Server 2005 database?

Package is created in VS.net 2008.
Actions/methods in the package will read and write from/to a SQL Server 2005 database.

Package would be executed/run from an SQL Server 2008 server.

Is this a supported scenario?

My DBA says no, but my thinking is this would be like if you made a VS.net 2008 SSIS package that accesses Oracle/DB2/Flat file.  Wouldn't SQL Server 2005 be just a data store in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSIS can access any SQL Server database version.  There is an OLE DB source component that will do this.

Comment: As well as any database with a compatible driver using OLE DB, ADO, ODBC or proprietary drivers.

Answer (score 2):

We ran many SSIS pacakages from a SQL Server 2008 database that got data from a SQL Server 2000 database before we upgraded all the databases. Your dba is incorrect.